# A closed instance in AWS cannot connect to external resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance

I need to set up an AWS instance that is closed from the Internet. I created such an instance, but it cannot connect to external network resources (for example, using the apt get update command)

I have tried to allow all inbound and outbound trafik in security group but it didnot help

Desired result:
My private instance should be able to connect to other insternet resources

Comment: Does the instance have a public IP? Does the VPC have an Internet Gateway?

Comment: More completely, see [Why can't my Amazon EC2 instance connect to the internet using an internet gateway?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ec2-connect-internet-gateway)

Comment: How did you "close" the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want to prevent traffic going *from* the Internet to your Amazon EC2 instance, but you want it to be able to have *outbound* connections to the Internet (and receive the response back).

There are two ways to restrict access between an Amazon EC2 instance and the Internet:

One way is to **use a Security Group that restricts Inbound access**. You might still want to allow access on port 22 (SSH) from your IP address, but otherwise remove all other **Inbound rules**. This will prevent any connections that are initiated from the Internet. Keep the Outbound rules with their default "Allow All" setting. This will permit **Outbound** connections to the Internet and the responses to these connections will be permitted to return.

Another way is to **put the instance in a private subnet**. This will automatically prevent the instance from being able to receive traffic from the Internet. You will need a NAT Gateway configured in a public subnet to permit Outbound traffic (charges apply). Putting the instance in a private subnet will also prevent inbound SSH connections, but you can use AWS Systems Manager Session Manager to connect to the instance.

In both cases you should *NOT* modify the Network Access Control Lists (NACLs). These should generally be left at their default "Allow all" settings.